# How to mark a message as "seen" by users?

Tags: database-design, architecture

I'm creating a chat. So, in one conversation can be lots of users and I need to mark a message when each of them seen it.

This is my architecture for conversations:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Rationale for Conversation & UserConversation?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably have a "User -- Message" associative class to store a status of the association.

[image: UserMessage]